# Using "Profile" Data

Tags: 7, views, users

I have used "Profiles 2" module, and created a form where users can input their profile data.

I have also defined a content type, say "Blog" for example, which has a title and a body. I have used "Views" module to generate the output.

The question is, I would like to display a line like :
'Posted By : '

Is there a way I can extract the data from Profiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you use relationships under advanced to first expose the Content:Author. Then you use relationships again which will now show the User:Profile relation. Now you will have access to all the user details :)

It should look like this when you are done:

[image]

Comment: I think this would show the username? I am trying to get the "First Name" field, which is an extension of the core profile i believe